# jquery stop delegated event from being called twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

My JS looks something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    menuClickHandler();
});
```

I have ajax based menu, `menuClickHandler` is used to make it work and resides in a separate JS file. `menuClickHandler` associates other functions that are associated to menu item. On click of menu item it calls a function associated with the menu item. Lets say I have menu item `Jump` and a function `JumpHandler` associated with it. Within `JumpHandler` there is one simple function as follows

```
functionA() {
    $("div.tree").on("click", ".branch", function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        //some code
    });
}
```

Scenario:
When the page is first loaded everything is fine, when I click on `Jump` `functionA' gets called and everything works fine. Now if click some other menu item and then click on`Jump`again,`JumpHandler`is called again and hence`functionA` gets called again resulting in click event on branch being bound twice. Can anyone tell me how do I remove/undelegate the delegated click event so that there is only click event bound to branch.

**jQuery version: v2.1.1**

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) instead of [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

> Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element per event type.

*Code*

```
$("div.tree").one("click", ".branch", function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    //some code
});
```

Comment: But this removes the click event after firing it once. In my case, if I am still viewing the same page and try to click second time on same element it won't work

Comment: @RajeshYogeshwar I guess Satpal has done it since you mentioned in your question `how do I remove/undelegate the delegated click event so that there is only click event bound to branch`

Comment: @gurvinder372, Yep you totally understood my reason

Comment: My bad then, apologies.

Answer (score 1):

if for some reason you have to bind click event inside `functionA`, then you can try `off`

```
functionA() {
    $("div.tree").off("click", ".branch" );
    $("div.tree").on("click", ".branch", function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        //some code
    });
}
```

or else you can do this binding outside the `functionA` since it is attach the event handlers to future branch elements regardless of when you invoke `functionA`

if you want to ensure that event is only fired once, then

```
functionA() {
    $("div.tree").on("click", ".branch", function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        //some code
       $("div.tree").off("click", ".branch" );
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because Once the function is called you have initialize a function in jquery which will execute without calling the function again. So before calling any function just turn off the jquery function

example:

```
$("div.tree").off("click", ".branch" );
functionA();

$("div.tree").off("click", ".branch" );
functionB();
```

Comment: I tried this as well for some reason this doesn't seem to work, there remain two click events every time functionA is called